# IPCS command for Shared memory and semaphore in Solaris, HP-UX and AIX

Tags: linux, solaris, aix, hp-ux

I know ipcs command for linux system, but now I'm looking for ipcs command for solaris, hp-ux and aix system, I have searched lot in websites, almost everyone suggest ipcs -am, ipcs -as or ipcs -a.

While I'm executing ipcs command in linux I got the following output,

```
cmd > ipcs -lm

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 32768
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 8388608
min seg size (bytes) = 1

cmd > ipcs -ls

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 128
max semaphores per array = 250
max semaphores system wide = 32000
max ops per semop call = 32
semaphore max value = 32767
```

But when I execute this command in aix, solaris and hp-ux I got nearly the following output from all these system:

```
cmd > ipcs -am

IPC status from /dev/mem as of Wed Aug 12 21:33:15 IST 2015
T        ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP  CREATOR   CGROUP NATTCH     SEGSZ  CPID  LPID   ATIME    DTIME    CTIME
Shared Memory:
m   1048576 0xffffffff D-rw------- pconsole   system pconsole   system      1 536870912 5177546 5177546 20:53:54 no-entry 20:53:54
m   1048577 0x78000012 --rw-rw-rw-     root   system     root   system      1 268435456 5112058 3801148 20:53:52 21:30:20 20:53:52
m   1048578 0x7800000c --rw-rw-rw-     root   system     root   system      1  16777216 5112058 3801148 20:53:52 21:30:20 20:53:52
m   1048579 0x61000010 --rw------- pconsole   system pconsole   system      1  10485760 5177546 5177546 20:53:54 no-entry 20:53:54
m 629145605 0xffffffff D-rw-------    kalai  egurkha    kalai  egurkha      1 536870912 9175052 9961658 22:36:08 21:33:06 22:36:08
m  22020103 0x0d02337e --rw-rw----     root   system     root   system      0      1440 7930086 7864444 20:57:46  6:10:14 22:19:05

cmd > ipcs -as

IPC status from /dev/mem as of Wed Aug 12 21:34:01 IST 2015
T        ID     KEY        MODE       OWNER    GROUP  CREATOR   CGROUP NSEMS   OTIME    CTIME
Semaphores:
s         1 0x62023470 --ra-r--r--     root   system     root   system     1 20:53:24 20:53:24
s   3145732 0x0100b38a --ra-ra-ra-     root   system     root   system     2 20:53:52 20:53:52
s   3145733 0xffffffff --ra-------     root   system     root   system     2 no-entry 20:53:52
s         8 0x8100000e --ra------- pconsole   system pconsole   system     4 22:58:27 20:53:54
s         9 0xa1003002 --ra-ra-ra- pconsole   system pconsole   system     2 21:29:28 20:53:56
s        10 0x010232b8 --ra-------     root   system     root   system     1  2:03:46 21:07:18
s        11 0x0101c6e8 --ra-ra-ra-     root    staff     root    staff     1 21:28:42 21:07:44
```

The problem is I can't able to find the values for following data:

```
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = ?
max seg size (kbytes) = ?
max total shared memory (kbytes) = ?
min seg size (bytes) = ?

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = ?
max semaphores per array = ?
max semaphores system wide = ?
max ops per semop call = ?
semaphore max value = ?
```

Please let me know how to find values for the above data or if you have any other solution for my requirements.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak to AIX.

AIX doesn't have a command that will programatically show the limits.

The closest you'll get for AIX is to use [this table](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/ipc_limits.htm) and code appropriately.

Comment: AIX  - `man shmget` may be helpful as well; `man semget` as well.

Answer (score 2):

For Solaris 10 and Solaris 11 you can use prctl command.
But you **must** read the manual as this is quite complicated when using zones and/or projects.

as an example for Solaris 11 for the current running global zone.

```
prctl $$
project.max-shm-memory
        privileged      40.3GB      -   deny                                 -
        system          16.0EB    max   deny                                 -
project.max-shm-ids
        privileged        128       -   deny                                 -
        system          16.8M     max   deny                                 -
--
zone.max-shm-memory
        usage               0B
        system          16.0EB    max   deny                                 -
zone.max-shm-ids
        usage               0
        system          16.8M     max   deny   

                          -
```

The above tells me that my global zone does not have any limit for the shared memory or semaphore ids.

```
# prctl $$| ggrep -A2 shm
project.max-shm-memory
        privileged      1.96GB      -   deny                                 -
        system          16.0EB    max   deny                                 -
project.max-shm-ids
        privileged        128       -   deny                                 -
        system          16.8M     max   deny                                 -
--
zone.max-shm-memory
        usage           1.89GB
        privileged      6.40GB      -   deny                                 -
--
zone.max-shm-ids
        usage               3
        system          16.8M     max   deny      

                       -
```

This second output tells me that my non-global zone is limited to 6.4GB of shared memory and used is close to 2GB.
For a list of resource controls you can see them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1460/rmctrls-3.html).
For Solaris 10 it isn't much different, but you need to check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/817-1592/rmctrls-1/index.html).